# Caractereres que ocupan dos posiciones en Oracle y al hacer validación en java solo ocupan una posición

Tags: java, oracle

tengo un problema al insertar caracteres especiales en Oracle.

El detalle es este:
Cuando valido un String en java el tamaño de la cadena me dice que es de 28,
entonces yo hago la validación de que se menor o igual a 28, entonces pasa la validación y llega al insert en Oracle, pero cuando se ejecuta la QUERY me manda error
porque el tamaño del campo es de 28 y están llegando 29 posiciones por el carácter especial.

Dejo el ejemplo de como java y Oracle lo interpretan.

- Java: Esta es una cadena de pruebä -> Tamaño 28
- Oracle: Esta es una cadena de pruebä -> Tamaño 29

¿Cómo puedo validar en java el tamaño de la cadena a como lo está interpretando Oracle, para que en java me mande las 29 posiciones?

Gracias,
Saludos.

Comment: En mi opinión, el problema deberías corregirlo del lado de Oracle, porque en realidad la cadena tiene 28 caracteres. Algunas preguntas para poder ayudarte, 1) ¿cual es el tipo exacto de la columna en tu tabla Oracle? 2) Cual es el resultado de la consulta siguiente? `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`. 3) Cual es el resultado de la consulta siguiente? `select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS'`

Comment: y el código??? Bienvenido al sitio Jesus, realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Realiza por favor las preguntas en base al documento [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0):

puedes convertir la cadena a un array de byte, asi te dara el tamaño exacto en bytes no en caracteres.

Ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("pruebä".length()); //Imprime 6
System.out.println("pruebä".getBytes().length); //Imprime 7
```

Comment: Cuidado con usar `getBytes()`, porque el resultado depende del charset por defecto del JVM, que puede ser que sea diferente entre tu y yo y OP. Es mas, todavía no se sabe cual es el charset que usa OP en su base de datos, así que, aunque parezca funcionar bien para un caracter especial, tal vez el resultado sea diferente para otro.